# Schedule Jobs Page on Multisite

Tags: cron, scheduled-job

I have a WordPress multisite with CiviCRM 4.7.24 also in multisite mode. The main site Scheduled Jobs page (civicrm/admin/job&reset=1) looks and works fine, but that page on other sites looks like this:

[image: Scheduled Jobs]

If I click "Add New Scheduled Job" I get this:

[image: Add New Scheduled Job]

which is not what I want. :(

Can anyone clarify why the additional sites don't have the regular Scheduled Jobs interface?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the correct interface.  I believe you're trying to compare the "List Scheduled Jobs" interface with the "Edit a single Scheduled Job" interface.  If you press "Edit" next to any scheduled job on your "main" site, it should look more or less identical to what you've posted above.

Crucially - when configuring Scheduled Jobs for multi-site, most jobs do NOT need to be run twice.  E.g. "Update Membership Status" works once across all contacts.  You DO need to replicate the "Send Mailings" scheduled job on each multi-site instance; you can copy the settings from the main site's "Send Mailings" interface.  I think you may need to change the name to something unique.

In my experience, the only site-specific scheduled jobs I create are "Send Mailings" and "Process Incoming Mail" - the latter because newly-created contacts won't be created as belonging to the correct "master group" for the domain otherwise.  IIRC even bounce processing is just done once for everyone.

Comment: "Crucially" is right... I haven't found any other documentation which states which scheduled jobs must be configured *per site* on a multi-site (a.k.a. multi-domain) install. It is the specific job itself which either is or is not "domain-aware," right? So ideally each job should be documented as to whether it needs to be run per site or not.

It seems it would be good to update https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/ with what you've stated here, assuming it's still accurate... and maybe a general caveat about jobs within multisite.

Comment: @Martin_W agreed!  Would you be willing to submit the documentation update?  The information in this post is still accurate.

Comment: Just submitted a documentation update merge request